# sanity checks: when do they become paranoid checks

Tags: assertions

I normally add lots of sanity check clauses in my code. In other words, lots of assertions where the code is instructed to "panic" (usually print as much information as possible when a certain condition doesn't hold and then exit). The point is, many of these sanity checks are obviously redundant one way or the other. On the other hand I've often been bitten by situations were I didn't add a sanity check judging it to be fairly obvious that it can't fail and was proven wrong. So the question is: are there any guidelines / best-practices to decide how much sanity checking is reasonable? Too much sanity checking obviously clutters the code and is a pain to maintain when assumptions change.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/165773)**

Comment: It is language-dependent. For languages where "undefined behavior" is possible, one must be extremely cautious. In fact, programs written in these languages cannot be made safe unless proven otherwise (e.g. Coq theorem prover, static analysis, or a equally-capable human theorist). On safer languages, and also on languages that supports (enforces) "member visibility" the right way, one can make use of limited visibility to eliminate some impossible scenarios from the analysis. This is where "code cohesion" helps analysis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is difficult to argue that:

- [All input is evil](https://web.archive.org/web/20171229112006/http://www.microsoft.com:80/mspress/books/sampchap/5957.aspx) is a solid unquestionable principle, because
  if we fail to conform to it, the resulting program will fail to
  conform to its requirements. Well we can conform to direct requirements, but, for example, consider requirement that says: "user X could be authorized by valid credential A". It is usually also meant that user Y shouldn't be able to authorize himself with halfvalid credential Y, but nonetheless [such things happen](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/02/extremely-critical-crypto-flaw-in-ios-may-also-affect-fully-patched-macs/).
- [Garbage in, Garbage out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) is not a way to process anything you
  get, because if something is wrong, then it is better to [fail
  fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) than to produce some undeterministic result and possibly
  corrupt the overall application.

So, if we [can't proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification) that some assert(check) is unnecessary, then the check isn't a paranoid one, but, rather, a completely normal protection mechanism for the program against unexpected. And taking into account that formal verification is not something you will use on everyday projects, asserts in code are a necessary burden.

But we have to be realists. It is nearly impossible to check everything whether in some mathematical model or in the working code. And not because there are [different kinds](https://web.archive.org/web/20151109024638/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) of exceptional situations exist (code defects, environment problems...), but because of the sheer complexity.

At best checking everything will lead to linear increase in LOC and some code bloat with duplication (and more code means more defects), at worst we will have [combinatorial explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion) and inconsistent, often wrong checks in multiple parts of the codebase.

But the most daunting and frustrating of all is the amount of details(exceptional to-check cases) that you have to juggle with.

---

So, how to adhere to principles that allow to write programs that behave more or less correctly and capable of dealing with unexpected situations, but at the same time do not demand enormous efforts to implement?

1. Acknowledge our limits and apply efforts accordingly from the conception till the implementation. Systems are complex and hard to understand, so we have to compartmentalize and isolate them as much as possible.
   It is important for any software, but with such rigid goals it is even more important - if we decide to get some correctness guarantees for tightly coupled 50-members classes, we are already moving in a wrong direction (possibly dooming us to [Sisyphean task](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyphus), where our asserts and checks will be just like a sieve for incorrect parameters, callbacks and dependencies).
   So, design classes and other units of work and interoperation judiciously - spaghetti code and [godobjects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) that provide trustworthy behaviour guarantees are a rare sight.
2. Use lines of defense and unclean input mechanics. Most units of work(classes, functions...) are also units of encapsulation as per se([class invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_invariant)), and they also act as intermediaries between different parts of the system. Function entry point checks, class constructors and accessors checks are the checkpoints in all possible senses - they are the main line of defence for class and the first one for his dependencies. So, if we can guarantee that class `VariableGate` will have only correct datamembers and allow to pass only correct variables to `VariableUser` class, then we have already cut a lot of checks from TODO list.
3. [Design by contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) augmented by heavy static analysis can be enormously useful. And I don't mean some comments claiming that `Foo` won't return `NULL`. I mean full-blown contracts, that are validated by compiler and runtime. They are either do not fail, or fail in a way, that you theoretically can't do anything wrong afterwards. They are the same function entry point checks, class constructors and accessors checks, just in another more formalized and useful form.
4. NullReferenceException, access violation or segmentation violation while dereferencing null pointers(references) is our friend. It is the most basic design-by-contract element for most of runtimes. Null is nil, as nothing, as something we cannot operate on. But it doesn't mean that we could just write `this.importantNotNullVar = varProvider.GetProbablyNotNullVar()` and be happy with it - it won't qualify as fail-fast. It means, for example, that chained calls `provider.GetExecutor().Do()` will fail if `GetExecutor()` is `null` whether you check it or use directly. But overall it is still better to adhere to the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) and use specialized nested method calls.

**P.S.:** There is also one topic of an utmost importance - correct state management. We can handle our exceptional cases with exceptions or return codes, or with complete app failure, but regardless of it our actions can corrupt the state of the data being processed. Ideally any operation should be transactional, so that any change to used data is either correct on success, or reverted on failure, but how to organize systems in such a way is an another question.

Comment: I mostly like this answer, but I take issue with your point number 1.  I agree that deciding to get correctness guarantees for tightly coupled 50-members classes is problematic, but I think the problem is tightly coupled 50-members classes.